# JSON file not changing

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using a jQuery ajax function and PHP file to change a JSON file but the file will not change even though I get the "Thanks!" alert. My jQuery, PHP, and JSON code is as follows.

jQuery file:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'savePoll.php',
        type : 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: 0,
        success: function () {alert("Thanks!"); },
        failure: function() {alert("Error!");}
})
```

PHP File:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('poll.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$data["answers"][$_POST]++;
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('poll.json', $newJsonString);
```

JSON File:

```
{
  "answers":[0,0,0,0,0]
}
```

My JSON file never changes but yet I still get my success alert. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just something that might come in handy: you can still see the response of your php script from within your browsers developer tools. This way you don't have to check your JSON file for success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the file the you want to change has 755 for its permission.

Answer (score 0):

1. This: `$data["answers"][$_POST]++;` doesn't look valid.
2. The `failure:` function will only trigger on a non 200 HTTP response.
3. The error in #1 is not serious enough to trigger an HTTP error. You would have to implement logic to make the page return a 400-level HTTP response code in order to ever have `failure:` trigger.

Comment: What exactly is the error in number 1? I am confused on what to put instead.

Comment: @Wowsk `$_POST` is an array. You cannot use an array as an array index.

Comment: For simplicity's sake I replace $_POST with 0 and still nothing happens. Are you sure there is nothing else that could be wrong.

Comment: Inspect the response. Output it in your JS code. Write a simple form that submits to it. Use a REST tool that lets you do it. Write a log file. Turn up `error_reporting`. Use Xdebug. Anything, just stop taking shots in the dark.